# Grails upgrading: paths incorrect in different locations

Tags: windows, grails, environment-variables

When I do Grails upgrades to new versions, I run into path and variable problems.   When I run `echo %GRAILS_HOME%` from cmd prompt, I always get `C:\grails\grails-2.3.7` -- regardless of what version is actually set elsewhere.

For instance, my actual `GRAILS_HOME` env variable is set to `C:\grails\current` - which contains v. 2.4.1  and Grails GGTS itself is point towards 2.4.1 also.

And yet if echo `%GRAILS_HOME%`, I always get `C:\grails\grails-2.3.7` as the path.

Comment: You said "my actual GRAILS_HOME env variable is set to C:\grails\current" and then said "if echo %GRAILS_HOME%, I always get C:\grails\grails-2.3.7".  Those cannot both be correct.  One common problem Windows users have is they set an environment variable in the system settings and expect it to appear in all of the already open shells, which isn't the case.  You need to open a new shell after changing the system setting in order to see the new variable.  Is that what is going wrong there?

Comment: yep.   I change the system var setting to 2.4.1, open a brand new fresh cmd window and echo %GRAILS_HOME% still has C:\grails\grails-2.3.7

Comment: You may have a User setting that is in conflict with a System setting or you may have scripts being executed when you open a new shell which are stepping on your settings.  In any case, this doesn't really have anything to do with Grails itself. This is a problem with managing your operating system environment.  Best of luck.

Comment: for now I just also copied 2.4.1 stuff into the 2.3.7 folder, and it works ok, but I'd like to figure this out the right way eventually. :)

Comment: @ry1633, please look at `gvm` command line utility. Really I am not sure it works just in the Windows `cmd`, but it works with the `cygwin`. I am sure it solves any your problems with many groovy/grails versions.